# jQuery, option to print content on link click

Tags: jquery, printing

I would like to be able to print a div with `overflow:auto` by clicking a link. Below is the code I am working with but it dose it on page load...

```
    printMe=window.open();
printMe.document.write($('.terms_and_conditions').html());
printMe.print();
printMe.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event like:

```
$(function(){
  $('#element_id').click(function(){
    printMe=window.open();
    printMe.document.write($('.terms_and_conditions').html());
    printMe.print();
    printMe.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to simplify this to just print the `.terms_and_conditions` without opening a new window?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS print, an example like this:

```
@media print {

    table, #MenuDiv, {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

   .fd_window, infoHide, #selectedItems, .fd_body {
        border: 0px solid;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #selectedItems table {
        visibility: visible!important;
        color: #000;
        display: block !important;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 8.5in;
    }

    #selectedItems table th, #form_selectedItems table td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 3px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
}
```